# Keyboard shortcut to end process for chrome tab

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome

Coding in JS, sometimes I goof up & creates an infinite loop. Other times, I hit a `debugger` inside a loop & I can't refresh quickly because the code has to finish running before the refresh occurs. Whatever the case, it is often times faster to crash the tab & then refresh.

- navigating to `chrome://crash` or `chrome://kill` doesn't work if a long-running process is executing, although it does work if I'm stuck at `debugger`
- clicking Window > Task Manager > Select tab > End Process & then refreshing takes too long.
- The extensions I've found no longer work (https://github.com/funroll/jollyroger,http://www.bitfalls.com/2013/09/build-chrome-extension-killing-chrome.html)

How can I achieve a keyboard shortcut to crash & refresh the current tab? native, 3rd party extensions, apps for OSX are fair game. 
Chrome version 44.

Comment: I think this question would fit better on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @BenJ I disagree. While chrome _in general_ isn't used primarily for programming, it's task management and dev tools _are_. This comes up all the time for me when developing web applications, and I think this is a great question that I wish there was a better solution for. I propose reopening it.

Comment: @YonaAppletree To each his own I suppose. I would have preferred if it was _moved_ (not closed) to Super User because the answer is also helpful for general computer use, not just coding (although that was the situation for the question, and probably a highly common one). I'd also like a better answer.

Answer (score 30):

A bit of an expansion on the previous answer:

Use System Preferences to link a keyboard shortcut to the "Task Manager" menu command (System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts), since the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> shortcut doesn't apply to Macs (at least not as of writing this post).

After that, you can use that keyboard shortcut in Chrome to pull up the Task Manager, where you can choose the unresponsive tab and select `End Process`.

Comment: Note that on macOS, while assigning the new keyboard shortcut, you can't use same as unix/windows which is `Shift` + `Esc` combination, it won't work. You must use another one. At my side, This shortcut assignment works `fn` + `Shift` + `Esc`.

Comment: I did what you said, Added "Task Manager" as menu title. And as Command, I inserted "Fn+Shift+Esc" so, when I am out of the input context the "Shift+Esc" Works. :)

Answer (score 23):

In Mac OS, the shortcut is not mapped to Chrome's Task Manager by default. Here is the way to get this mapped.

Go to `System Preferences` > `Keyboard`. Select `Keyboard Shortcuts` tab > `Application Shortcuts` in the list on the left and click the `Plus` button. Select `Google Chrome` in the `Application` drop down, type `Task Manager` in the `Menu Title` input, click on the `Keyboard Shortcut` field and press your shortcut of choice. Use Chrome's Task Manager to kill the desired process.

Comment: For whatever reason I wasn't able to add shift + escape here, but ctrl+escape worked fine.  Thanks for the tip, since chrome tends to crash a task if you update the code while it's stopped in the debugger, I need to kill the task far too often.

Answer (score 10):

You can

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>.
2. Select the tab or extension.
3. Click **`End Process`**.

Comment: I saw this in another SO answer, but Shift + Esc doesn't do anything for me. Can you confirm this works on OSX?

Comment: It works on Win7, Win8, Win8.1. No idea about other OS. Sorry :(

Comment: Shift + Esc *does not* work on OS X, the operating system the OP is using.

Comment: It works in Linux (at least Fedora 28) too

Answer (score 0):

You can go through below steps:

```
1. Shift + Esc
2. Select Tab
3. And then click "End Process".
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this trick is cumbersome, but you dont have to use Mouse/TrackPad to access the Task Manager ;)

Also, once you get used to it, a quick succession of keys will display the "Chrome Task Manager"

1. Cmd+L           (To go to the Address Bar)
2. Hit Tab           (To go
   to the Wrench icon)
3. Hit Space       (To open the settings menu)
4. Press "T"       (Select Tools)
5. Hit Enter        (Go inside the menu)
6. Press "T"       (Select the Task Manager)
7. Hit Enter        (Opens
   the Task Manager...Viola!!)

(Try the key sequence couple of times and it's quite easy)

Really wish they had just provided one direct shortcut similar to windows (Shift+ESC)

Comment: `Cmd+L` -> `Tab` shifts your focus back to the active page unfortunately now.